# How to check whether a range of cells is a subset of another range?

Tags: google-sheets

## My Problem

I have a few lists on a Google Sheet, each kept in a column of cells. One of the list is the Master list, and I would like to make sure that the elements in the other lists are also present in master.

[image]

For example, `list1` and `list2` are valid, but `list3` is invalid because `x` is not present in `master`.

Duplication is orthogonal to the question - I can use [`UNIQUE`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093198?hl=en) if I'd like to check for uniqueness as well.

## What Have I Tried

- [`LOOKUP`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3256570?hl=en) only works for a single value and for sorted ranges
- Using [Google Sheets Query Language](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/querylanguage): Did not find any set / list operations

## My Question

**How can I check whether all the values in an unsorted cell range exist in another cell range?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> LOOKUP only works for a single value

Not true.

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(AND(MATCH(I2:I4,H2:H5,0)))
```

- MATCH to lookup the row of I2:I4 in the MasterList
- AND to combine all matches and throw N/A,If any of the values are not found.
- ARRAYFORMULA to use arrays in formulas.

Comment: Does it matter if the lists are sorted or not?